# Erro de chamada de procedura

Tags: mysql, sql, python, python-3.x, mariadb

Estou com um problema na hora de chamar uma `procedure` dentro de uma `function` no `SQL`. Quando faço a chamada da função `CHECK_LOGIN` pelo `SGBD`, faz a operação sem nenhum problema, mas eu preciso fazer essa operação por um código em python e é nesse local onde ocorre o erro.

**Trecho em python**

```
cur.execute('select CHECK_LOGIN(%s, %s)', (header['USER_INFO']['NAME'], header['USER_INFO']['KEY']))
```

Apost o python passar por essa linha de código ele testa a validação e retorna o valor `-1`, entretanto, não é feito o *update* do usuário, mantendo os campos `user_key` e `valid` sem valores.

> **Qual poderia ser o motivo do erro?** *(código foi testado em duas maquinas diferentes e o erro continuou a persistir)*
>
> `header['USER_INFO']['NAME']` contem um nome de usuário.
>
> `header['USER_INFO']['KEY']` contem um md5 de 32 caracteres.

**Banco de dados**

```
create table user(
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(80) not null,
    login varchar(16) not null,
    user_key char(32),
    valid date,
    primary key(id)
);

create table login_info(
    id integer not null auto_increment,
    user integer not null,
    day date not null,
    key_access char(32) not null,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(user) references user(id)
);

DELIMITER $

create procedure NEW_USER(IN uname varchar(80), IN ulogin varchar(16))
begin
    insert into user(name, login, user_key) values(uname, ulogin, '');
end$

create procedure FIRST_ACCESS(IN pid Integer, IN ukey char(32))
begin
    DECLARE valid_day date;
    set valid_day = DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

    update user set user_key = ukey, valid = valid_day where id = pid;
end$

create function CHECK_LOGIN(ulogin varchar(16), ukey char(32)) returns Integer DETERMINISTIC
begin
    DECLARE _id integer;
    DECLARE _key char(32);
    DECLARE _date date;

    select id into _id from user where login = ulogin;
    select user_key into _key from user where id = _id;

    if _key = '' then
        call FIRST_ACCESS(_id, ukey);
        return -1;
    elseif _key = ukey then
        select valid into _date from user where id = _id;
        if _date < curdate() then
            return 1;
        end if;
        return 0;
    else
        return 2;
    end if;
    return 3;
end; $

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o Erro.

Não estava salvando as alterações porque não ouve a confirmação utilizando o `db.commit()` antes de finalizar a conexão do banco de dados.